# Is it legal to study while on a tourist Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, study, eu, change-purpose-of-travel

If, say, you acquired a 90-day tourist Schengen visa, would it be legal to use it for the purpose of visiting a language course or a university class? Or do you have to apply for a special education visa if you have such intents?

Answers linking to official EU pages on that matter would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: @LiamWilliam They would know because you have to tell them (when you apply, you explain the purpose of the travel, submit an itinerary, etc.).

Comment: @Annoyed True although I have never heard of the government monitoring such.  Deleted comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official documents can be found on the [EU website](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/index_en.htm). In fact, there is no such thing as a “tourist” Schengen visa, the main distinction is between a short-stay (no more than 90 days in a 180-day period) visa and long-stay (national) visas. But you must always specify the purpose of your journey on the application form.

The standard application form (annex 1 of the [visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:243:0001:0058:EN:PDF)) includes a “Study” checkbox and both the visa code and the *[Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf)* also discuss at length the type of supporting documentation that must be provided in this case. In particular:

> 2. for journeys undertaken for the purposes of study or other types of training:
>
> (a) a certificate of enrolment at an educational establishment for the purposes of attending vocational or theor­etical courses within the framework of basic and further training;
>
> (b) student cards or certificates of the courses to be attended;

All that should be enough to establish that studying or taking classes on a short-stay Schengen visa is officially allowed and completely above board. Now, if you pretend to be a tourist and submit a complete itinerary while the real goal of your trip in fact is to attend a course, it could be grounds to refuse the visa (if caught, obviously).

Of course, the short duration of stay (even compared to the UK's six-month general visitor visa) severely limits the type of classes you could possibly attend.

Comment: TL;DR Yes _______________

Answer (score 1):

No special visa for the purpose of studying required. Of course, you're not able to get a job and work officially. The purpose of a visa is necessary in the case of a long-term (over 90 days) visa.

From my experience, I had a 90-day EU visa and was able to visit a 6-week intensive language course. After that I was travelling to EU several times without the hassle.

Let's imagine if you wanted to visit a conference and attend several classes you're interested in, would you have to get a visa? Answer is no.

Comment: While it makes sense logically to me as well, it would be nice to find an official answer.

Comment: For example the UK does not allow such an arrangement: http://www.lse.ac.uk/study/informationForInternationalStudents/visasAndImmigration/ifYouHaveANon-StudentVisa.aspx