# What constitutes "studying" in the UK for visa purposes?

Tags: visas, uk, legal, terminology, study

A [comment on this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25537/444), points to a [document](http://www.lse.ac.uk/study/informationForInternationalStudents/visasAndImmigration/ifYouHaveANon-StudentVisa.aspx), which specifies that:

> **You cannot study in the UK with General Visitor or Business Visitor permission** and you cannot register at LSE if you have permission as a general visitor for any kind of programme of study.

What constitutes *study*?

During my 2-month stay in London, I took several walk-in dance classes.  Would this technically be a violation?

What about something more regular, but not accredited? A 6-week Karate course, for instance?

*Do I ever need to worry about accidentally taking an illegal course or class?  Or will any eligible institution know to ask for my residency/visa status before admitting me?*

Comment: How many days per week for the Karate class? Would it be the main purpose of your visit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document you quote is aimed at those pursuing academic qualifications.

[You can pursue up to 30 days of study on a General Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/permitted-study-when-visiting-the-uk/permitted-study), with some restrictions.

From the linked document:

> You can:
>
> - take your 30 days study in one go or over a number of shorter periods
> - use the time for recreational courses such as activity courses or arts and crafts courses, eg horse-riding, painting or sailing
> - study toward a qualification if the course is at an accredited institution
>
> You can’t:
>
> - use any of your 30 days to study English at an institution without accreditation

Comment: That's useful, but not a complete answer. Can I take a 6-week Karate class? Does that constitute greater than 30 days? Does it constitute "study"?

Comment: @Flimzy - Point no 1 in the link answers your question. I am not sure what more information do you want. Any more clarifications contact the British embassy.

Comment: Actually *point 2* answers it more directly...

Comment: When the page says "Courses that are recreational and don’t count towards a qualification don’t have to follow this rule.", that's the rule about studying only at an accredited institution.