# Can Indian nationals not visit the UK for a short course (not by a university)?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, study

I applied to a short-term course (5 weeks) that is arranged by a private organization. My application was declined by the organizers because they said that Indian nationals will not be granted visas to the UK for short courses unless it is affiliated with a university (and this was not).

Is this true, and if so, are there alternative ways to get a visa to the UK to attend the course? I am well qualified, have a current job, good finances and can support myself for the duration (accommodation is being arranged by the organization in any case).

Comment: How about distance learning?

Comment: For courses in colleges, you need a letter from the college(organizers) to file with your visa. If they say no, then it is next to impossible to get a visa. If you do enter with a different visa(tourist) to attend the course, you will be breaking the conditions of your visa and if caught might be deported, which is not a good scenario.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25558/444

Comment: The best way to do this study legally is to find a college that is on the approved list and offers a similar course.

Answer (score 2):

There is [the list of schools](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/302170/Tier_4_Register_of_Sponsors_2014-04-09.pdf) where you can study with [Student Visa](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/overview).

If your private school is not in this list it is no possible to study there for you.