# I'm planning to visit a summer school in the Schengen zone. What kind of visa should I apply for?

Tags: visas, schengen

I will be attending a summer school which will last 10 days.  I want to know: for applying for a Schengen visa, is the purpose of my trip considered as touristic or study?

Comment: If your journey is contingent upon taking the course, select 'study'. Otherwise 'tourism'

Comment: It may depend on the nature of the summer school.  Many such events do not award any academic credit and are really more in the nature of academic conferences, in which case a business visa might be appropriate.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25537/is-it-legal-to-study-while-on-a-tourist-schengen-visa?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

### Choose the main visit purpose

On the [Schengen visa application form](http://www.mzv.cz/public/9e/20/cc/1192009_1138997_Schengen_visa_ApplicationForm.pdf) you must fill the following section:

[image]

The relevant question is whether you will spend most of your days studying or traveling.

- If you spend 9 or less days traveling - mark the 'Study' checkbox
- If you spend 10 days traveling - mark both 'Study' and 'Tourism'
- If you spend 11 or more days traveling - mark the 'Tourism' checkbox

In the study visa application you should include the details about your tourist trip and vice versa.

### Documents required if your main purpose is studying

According to the *[Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf)* you will need to provide the following documents to support your visa application:

> 2. for journeys undertaken for the purposes of study or other types of training:
>
> (a) a certificate of enrolment at an educational establishment for the purposes of attending vocational or theor­etical courses within the framework of basic and further training;
>
> (b) student cards or certificates of the courses to be attended;

If the summer school is unable to provide such documentation (e.g. it's more of a conference), apply for a different visa type.

Comment: +1 good advice but a small quibble regarding the terminology. Tourism, study or “other” are not so much visa types than a purpose for the stay. What you get is a Schengen visa in any case and there is nothing on the visa identifying it as a “study” visa. Studying is perfectly allowed, e.g. on a multiple-entry visa that was obtained for regular business trips.