# Is it possible to attend coding bootcamps or trainings while travelling?

Tags: schengen, legal, study, pakistani-citizens

I am planning to travel Europe in late September this year. This will be a 15-20 days trip.

I am Software Developer by profession and I am thinking to attend some coding bootcamps or training while traveling.

I could not stay for more than a week at a place so is it possible to attend some nearby institutes or where can I find short courses or training camps?

The destinations I have in mind are, Italy, France, Belgium, Netherlands.

I am alright if it is paid but not too expensive as I am not looking for a detailed course.

My question is related to both the legal aspect and the training I can enroll in while my stay in any of the mentioned countries.

Note: I am a Pakistani national and my VISA of type C is valid for one year with a max of 90 days stay and the purpose I mentioned while filling the application form was **Business**.

Comment: Do you ask whether such courses exist or whether your visa allows you to do that? For the 2nd one we need to know where are you from and what is your visa plan.

Comment: Are you asking if your visa allows you pay for and attend training courses; or are you asking if there are training courses available that are less than a week in France, Belgium or Netherlands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it legal to study while on a tourist Schengen visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25537/is-it-legal-to-study-while-on-a-tourist-schengen-visa)

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: Please also add your nationality @Sajjad and the type of your visa (C?).

Comment: I'm from Pakistan and my visa type is C

Comment: Thanks for adding the details. I have voted to reopen and as soon as a few more (experienced) users have followed suit, your question will be reopened and hopefully answered soon. Have a good trip!

Answer (score 5):

As outlined in an [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/25556/9009) to a related question by @Relaxed:

> Official documents can be found on the [EU
>   website](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/index_en.htm).
>   In fact, there is no such thing as a “tourist” Schengen visa, the main
>   distinction is between a short-stay (no more than 90 days in a 180-day
>   period) visa and long-stay (national) visas.

Since there is no such thing as a "study" visa or a "bootcamp" visa, you should be fine undertaking the mentioned activities in any country of the Schengen area on a regular short-stay visa. The only restriction is that you must not be paid for participating, but I presume most bootcamps are the other way around.